# Laravel session Convert tags to html entity

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, notifyjs

I want to convert this message value to an html entity :

```
return redirect('/')->withErrors(['success' => 'register done .<br> Thanks for register.']);
```

but in my blade :

```
@if($errors->first('success'))
       $('.top-right').notify({
        message: { html: " <b>{{ $errors->first('success') }}</b> " },
        type: 'success',
        fadeOut: { enabled: true, delay: 7000 }
    }).show();
@endif
```

{{ $errors->first('success') }}
 show this:

```
register done .<br> Thanks for register
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use :

```
{!! $errors->first('success') !!}
```

instead of

```
{{ $errors->first('success') }}
```